# Is there any uniform way to align console output in C++

Tags: c++, printf, wstring

I met a requirement to align the output text in the console. The output texts are stored as `std::wstring` and encoded as `UTF-8`. The thing that makes this task tricky is, the output text contains both ASCII characters and Japanese characters, e.g. `ナ5回1ション4aスF`. Use `setw()` or `wprintf(L"%-10s")` directly can't align it due to the different widths of ASCII characters and Japanese characters.
For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    wstring s[] = {L"短3マ231ー○",L"のき3ーナ",L"ぐマ",L"ろにト"};
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)    wcout << setw(10) << s[i] <<123<< endl;
}
```

will be like:

```
    短3マ231ー○123
     のき3ーナ123
       ぐマ123
      ろにト123
```

But it works perfectly if the text only contain ASCII characters.

I know I can just write a new function for aligning it on my own, but I'm wondering if there already have a reliable solution for it.

Comment: Various Unicode libraries provide means for determining the width of a Unicode character. Of course, that doesn't mean that whatever system font is used will agree with the Unicode library's ideas, but it usually works. You'll need to explore what Unicode libraries are available on your operating system, or whether your operating system has a built-in Unicode library that provides this information.